# Laravel on ubuntu

Tags: server, apache2, laravel

I have successfully created a laravel 5 project. I created a route to `test.test/me`. If i visit `test.test` in my browser, it will display the laravel homepage. But if i visit `test.test/me` browser will display

Not Found

The requested URL /me was not found on this server.

However, if i use the `php artisan serve` command and use the php server the routing will work `localhost:8000/` will display my route. I don't know what to do.

I run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and i use Apache server. Anybody can help? Please help sustain a developer's ambition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh! I just discovered the problem. It was from my VirtualHost file `test.test.conf`.

Because I copied the `000-default.conf` into `test.test.conf` it did not include the `<Directory>` directive:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/sites/test/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I just added this, and it is working fine now!